# Why does the space of fraction is larger in front-end?

Tags: front-end

Today I installed the Wolfram Mathematica on my new laptop. I open it and the fraction show in front-end is normal. However, it becomes abnormal when I restarted the system(Win 10). Please see the screenshoot. Does someone encounter this?

[image]

In additon, I also notice the postion of refresh button is not normal:

[image]

---

**Update:**

This problem only occurs in the newest Windows 10 release. I have tested the Mathematica from 9 to 12. The problem always occur in all the versions.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a few more details on your setup? In particular, what is the magnification setting in Mathematica, what is your Display Scaling setting in Windows, and can you add a screenshot where you select the fraction?

Comment: @LukasLang Please see update.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to answer this from an experienced software developer's perspective.

Wolfram is written to support a number of platforms and processor architectures. The widgets that you see on the front end are usually third party additions, e.g. QT, but Wolfram may well be using their own. However, these widgets do try to be compatible with most systems, and usually they are. Windows 10 does things differently these days, especially now that it supports more accessibility for visually the challenged. They also have work on mobile devices where "real estate" on the screen is limited.

I know for a fact, that designing a front end is problematic as the system doesn't always give the correct width/height for various screen objects, and one has to apply fudge factors to cater for different platforms. 
It is increasingly becoming impossible to support all platforms and all devices at the same time. Even programming Windows 10 apps is different to programming a true Windows 64 bit desktop application, and then, when an app is tested on various devices, there are errors in the layout. This is exacerbated when one's code is written to be portable, (Java for example). I would suggest that you are seeing some of these errors.

When it comes to fonts, the system will usually give you a near match to the one requested, but they do differ in some aspects, such as character pitch and kerning. It also depends on which fonts the platform supports and how closely the GDI can match the application's requested font. Some graphics devices can give a very good rendition of the requested font, but not all. Again it depends on the platform, drivers, etc. So despite using a common font, when it comes to spacing and character height, the GDI wont measure the character properly, and you either see excessive or cramped spacing.

None of these observations suggest that the platform you are using is not working properly, its is just that the platform's display is most probably different than the platform it was designed on (probably Unix). I would have thought that the quality department should have picked this up, but if it only affects the display on one platform and is not too excessive, then it becomes a lower priority. If the display is readable and the maths is right, then realistically you're on a winner.

I hope this helps to explain what you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This problem only occurs in the newest Windows 10 release. I have tested the *Mathematica* from 9 to 12. The problem always occur in all the version.

Comment: While your post makes perfect sense, there are examples of programs on both Mac and Windows that don't exhibit these graphical oddities, such as Adobe Illustrator etc.